# Django custom User model throwing SystemCheckError - The field 'username' clashes with the name 'username'

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

I'm writing a custom User model in Django, inheriting it from `AbstractUser` as is mentioned in the official Django tutorials. But this throws an error.

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
redditauth.RedditUser.username: (models.E006) The field 'username' clashes with the field 'username' from model 'redditauth.reddituser'.
```

Here is the code I wrote for the custom user model.

```
class RedditUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, primary_key=True, validators=[validate_reddit_username], max_length=20)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    USERNAME_FIELD = username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['token']

    def reddit(self):
        with open('secret.json', 'r') as f:
            secret = json.load(f)

        return praw.Reddit(client_id=secret['client_id'], client_secret=secret['client_secret'],
                           refresh_token=self.token, user_agent='Plan-Reddit by /u/SkullTech101')
```

I have tried renaming it to something other than `username`, thinking that maybe there was already field named `username` in `AbstractUser`, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Use a string, not a variable: `USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Alasdair pointed out, I had to use a string, not a variable, when setting the value of `USERNAME_FIELD`.

So in my case it was

```
USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
```